# use an array from Google Sheets to create a data list in html that can be served to a Google Apps Script for Autocomplete a Text Input

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, modal-dialog

I have been struggling for a couple days to build a simple interface for my colleagues to record every customer interaction. They will input the following:

1. Name of Customer (Autocomplete feature, from a superset of all names in a column in the spreadsheet)
2. Date of Interaction
3. Summary of the Interaction
4. Prospects (Hot, Warm, Tepid, Cold)

My problem is in getting the Autocomplete working.

I have seen threads where @Tanaika has beautifully laid down the Server Side, HTML+JS, etc. but I am unable to get this to work. My files are attached. Thanks for your time!

HTML+JS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
     label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    }   
    </style>
    
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
    function submitForm() {
      google.script.run.appendRowFromFormSubmit(document.getElementById("feedbackForm"));
      document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("thanks").style.display = "block";
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <datalist id="datalist">
    <?! 
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Ms0Cny3f-XaXS26s5AnrDT4H9c8p8OKRfwxPIQ9_CU/edit#gid=16760772"; 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Pipeline");
    var rng = ws.getRange('D2:D')
    var rangeArray = rng.getValues();
    var filArray = rangeArray.filter(function (el) {return el[0] != ""}).flat();  // Modified
    console.info("hello read the data");
    for (var i = 0; i < datalist.length; i++) { !?>
    <option value="<?= datalist[i] ?>">
    <?! } !?>
  </datalist>
  <div>
  <div id="form">
  <h1>Record Interaction</h1>
  <form id="feedbackForm">
    <label for="name">Parent Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" list="datalist"><br><br>

    <label for="doi">Date of Interaction</label>
    <input id="today" type="date" name="doi"><br><br>

    <label for="feedback">Interaction Summary</label>
    <textarea rows=4 cols=35 id="feedback" name="feedback">Enter Interaction Summary Here...
         </textarea><br><br>

    <div>
      <label for="temperature">Likely Candidate?</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="Hot" name="temperature" value="Hot">
      <label for="yes">Hot</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="Warm" name="temperature" value="Warm">
      <label for="yes">Warm</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="Tepid" name="temperature" value="Tepid">
      <label for="yes">Tepid</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="Cold" name="temperature" value="Cold">
      <label for="no">Cold</label><br><br>

      <input type="button" value="Submit Interaction" onclick="submitForm();">
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="thanks" style="display: none;">
    <p>Thank you for speaking to our customers!</p>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CODE.GS

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Customer Engagement')
      .addItem('Record Interaction', 'showDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('RecordInteraction.html')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(600);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Please Enter Details');
}
function readData() {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Ms0Cny3f-XaXS26s5AnrDT4H9c8p8OKRfwxPIQ9_CU/edit#gid=16760772"; 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Pipeline");
  var rng = ws.getRange('D2:D')
  var rangeArray = rng.getValues();
  var filArray = rangeArray.filter(function (el) {return el[0] != ""}).flat();  // Modified
  console.info("hello read the data")
  return filArray;
}

function activateSheetById(sheetId) {
 
  //Access all the sheets in the Google Sheets spreadsheet
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();

  //Filter out sheets whose Ids do not match
  var sheetsForId = sheets.filter(function(sheet) {
    return sheet.getSheetId() === sheetId;
  });

  //If a sheet with the Id was found, activate it
  if(sheetsForId.length > 0)
    sheetsForId[0].activate();
}

function appendRowFromFormSubmit(form) {
  var row = [form.name, form.doi, form.feedback, form.temperature];
  console.info("Appending Row");
  activateSheetById(2059810756);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(row);
}

function makeUL(array) {
      // Create the list element:
    var namelist = document.createElement('ul');

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return namelist;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modification points:

- In your HTML, the template is used. In this case, please use `createTemplateFromFile` instead of `createHtmlOutputFromFile`.
- The scriptlet of `<?!= ... ?>` is `Force-printing scriptlets` (`like printing scriptlets except that they avoid contextual escaping.`). [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets)

I thought that these are the reasons for your issue. When these points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### Google Apps Script side:

##### From:

```
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('RecordInteraction.html')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(600);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Please Enter Details');
}
```

##### To:

```
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index.html');
  html.data = readData();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate().setWidth(400).setHeight(600), 'Please Enter Details');
}
```

- Here, your function of `readData()` is used.

#### HTML and Javascript side:

##### From:

```
<datalist id="datalist">
  <?! 
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit#gid=16760772"; 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Pipeline");
  var rng = ws.getRange('D2:D')
  var rangeArray = rng.getValues();
  var filArray = rangeArray.filter(function (el) {return el[0] != ""}).flat();  // Modified
  console.info("hello read the data");
  for (var i = 0; i < datalist.length; i++) { !?>
  <option value="<?= datalist[i] ?>">
  <?! } !?>
</datalist>
```

##### To:

```
<datalist id="datalist">
<? data.forEach(e => { ?>
  <option value="<?= e ?>">
<? }); ?>
</datalist>
```

### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: Magic! Thanks. Now when I shared this sheet (Full Editor Access) with Collaborators, the html is served to the Collaborator, but function AppendRowFromFormSubmit does not end up appending the form data. Should I open a separate question for this please? Also, I'd prefer not to deploy to webapp, unless that's the only option. Thanks.

Comment: @Rajesh Panchanathan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. At that time, when you include more information, it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Answer (score 0):

#### Example of making suggestions to a email dialog

html:

```
<div id="emaildialog">
      Recipient Search:<br />
      <input id="rec" type="text" oninput="getSuggestions();" placeholder="Enter Search String slowly. Yellow=accessing server" size="50" /><br />
      Suggestions:<br />
      <div id="sugdiv" style="width:100%;background-color:#ffffff;"></div>
      Recipients:<br />
      <textarea id="recipients" cols="50" rows="4" placeholder="Sent to first recipient. Remaining recipients are blind copied."></textarea><br />
      Message:<br />
      <textarea id="msg" cols="50" rows="4" placeholder="Enter message to send with the attachments." >This is a copy of our apps Final Report.</textarea><br>
      <input type="button" id="send" value="Create PDF and Send Email" onClick="createAndSendReport();" />
    </div>
```

Javascript(With JQuery):

```
function updateDiv(vA){
    var s='';
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
      s+='<input type="button" id="btn-' + i + '" onClick="selectRecipient1(\'btn-' + i + '\')" value="' + vA[i][0] + '" />';
    }
    $('#sugdiv').html(s);
  }

function getSuggestions(){
    var txt=$('#rec').val();
    if(txt.length>0){
      $('#rec').css('background','yellow');
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(vA){
        $('#rec').css('background','white');
        //updateSelectList(vA);
        updateDiv(vA);
      })
      .getSuggestions(txt)
    }else{
      updateSelectList([]);
    }
  }
```

Google Apps Script:

```
function getSuggestions(s){
  
  if(s){
    var vA=[];
    var cA=getAllContacts();
    for(var i=0;i<cA.length;i++){
      if(cA[i].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(s.toLowerCase())>-1){
        vA.push([cA[i][0]]);
      }
    }
  }
  return vA;
}
```

This code is about 5 years old.  It's still running in the original application

Comment: this is very helpful too - will incorporate for other requirement.